# magento 1.9.3.4 doesn't load CSS and JS on frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, redis, linux, cm-redissession

I am running Magento 1.9.3.4 new install on a HP 9400 server with Quad Core AMD 2380x8, 32Mb RAM with ubuntu-server 14.04 and Webmin/Virtualmin Pro Panel

I have 3 stores that load dynamically by https://nilandtrading.com/fishing store1 or store2 or store3 etc. Store1 and store3 load OK but store2 (fishing) will not load any CSS or JS. I have tried the URL on 3 different browsers (No I.E. as I don't do windows), with the same result.

Inspecting with Console I get countless errors like "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" and "Uncaught ReferenceError: Mage is not defined" and GET errors for the JS scripts.

None or the other stores show errors, since each store is using the same index.php and the rest of Magento I don't get why 2 stores work and one won't. I have shut down redis cache and any file and Database cache. Must have cleared them a 100 times now. I have been searching for an answer for a week now and just don't know anything else to do other then starting over. For give me not listing the steps I have done as they are too numerous to list here. Perhaps some one could give me a lead where to go next?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your base url for the js and css files is incorrectly set for the store.

Go to `System->Configuration`
Change the `current configuration scope` to your store (fishing)
Open the General->Web tab on the left
Open the `Unsecure` and `Secure` tabs on the right hand side.

Check your Base Skin URL and Base Javascript URL settings.
They should be something like

```
{{unsecure_base_url}}skin/ 
{{unsecure_base_url}}js/
{{secure_base_url}}skin/ 
{{secure_base_url}}js/
```

I suspect you've set them to fishing/js or similar

Comment: This is odd as I have looked at this many times and it seems to be exactly as dermatz indicated. You can't add a slash to "Base Link URL" [{{secure_base_url}}] as it is removed on save. But as far and the 3 stores, camping, fishing and hunting all the right hand check-boxes are marked. However you saw something I did not so I looked at it again for each store and found nothing, then an idea hit me!!! I have the Magento backend set up on redis, so I set the sessions and the rest back to files and Wholla I found the error after disabling Redis cache

Answer (score 0):

(solved)
This is odd as I have looked at this many times and it seems to be exactly as dermatz indicated. You can't add a slash to **Base Link URL** `[{{secure_base_url}}]` 
as it is removed on save. But as for and the 3 stores, camping, fishing and hunting all the right hand check-boxes are marked. However you saw something I did not so I looked at it again for each store and found nothing, then an idea hit me!!!

I have the Magento backend set up on redis, so I set the sessions and the rest, *back to files* and Wolla I found the error, Seems the base URL for the fishing store was http[s]://nilandtrading.com/fishing/ and I was never able to see it before as I had checked many times. Got rid of the /fishing/ and all works. I was lead to believe sessions was for the frontend, but it must effect the backend also!

What sucks about Magento and Redis is there is no button to suspend Redis while editing. You have to do it by the CLI or boot and then Magento is not happy as the local.xml is looking for it, so who wants to edit their local.xml all the time. There is redismanager on github but it only flushes and the keys are instantly regenerated, "errors and all